# Repeater Control with Objects?

Tags: asp.net

I was told to use a Repeater control in what I am doing  which is a "Data Entry" screen with ASP.NET controls -a standard "address" like form. In cases, the fields on the form will repeated twice, once for the original values, one for the changed values. I have not used this control before but it seems like I have to bind to a database. Instead, I have an Entity object that has been obtained via a Repository. Can I bind to an object like this?

```
[DataContract()]
    public class RON
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Comments { get; set; }
```

Then, I have my ASP.NET fields which I used the following with CSS to get the fields to line up. Can I put this in an ItemTemplate?

```
 <div class="row1">
    <div class="label">  
       ID: 
    </div>  
    <div class="value">
       <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will likely want to do something in your *PageLoad* such as:

```
List<SomeBusinessObj> MyEntityCollection = Repository.Load();
```

You then can bind your entity object collection to the repeater control using the *DataSource* property of the repeater control.

```
rptrMyRepeater.DataSource = MyEntityCollection;
```

Then by calling *DataBind* on that control, your collection will become bound to that control.

```
rptrMyRepeater.DataBind();
```

Then all you need to do is use the Repeater's databound event to apply your custom properties to the repeater's controls.

```
protected void rptrExample_OnItemDataBound(object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs Args)
{
 if (Args.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || Args.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
 {
  SomeBusinessObj Obj = (SomeBusinessObj)Args.Item.DataItem;

  Label LabelControl = (Label)Args.Item.FindControl("lblSomeLabel");
  LabelControl.Text = Obj.CustomProperty;
 }
}
```

The *ItemDataBound* event will be called for each row item, so each time it is called you will be working on the that row item's controls and databound object.

---

An alternative approach would be to directly databind within markup, not using the *OnItemDataBound* event.

```
<asp:Label Text='<%# ((MyObjects.SomeBusinessObj)Container.DataItem).CustomProperty %>' runat="server" />
```

The direct cast avoids the call into *DataBinder.Eval*, and the overhead of reflection.

Comment: Thanks! Do I surround my markup with the ItemTemplate from the Repeater?

Comment: Yes, within your ItemTemplate, HeaderTemplate, etc.

Comment: I tried this but the direct cast in the markup doesn't understand the type (SomeBusinessObj) or (RON) in my case. How do you let it know?

Comment: You will need to include the full namespace declaration with your type. (ie. MyNamespace.SomeBusinessObj)

Comment: @cweston Thank you soooo much. I've re-written presentation code so many times because I couldn't find the correct keywords to search to find out how to get access to a class' data members through a databound collection. Your "need to include the full namespace" comment regarding how to cast the data item is what I've been searching for for years. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 4):

You can
you should use the ItemTemplate to display the markup for each object, you can use the HeaderTemplate and FooterTemplate to display those also.

for example :

```
<asp:Repeater id="myRepeater" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MyProperty1") %>,
    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MyProperty2") %>,
    <br />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

after defining the templates, just set the datasource of the repeater to your collection and databind it

```
myRepeater.DataSource = myCollection;  
myRepeater.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can bind a repeater to any list.  So you can add the original and changed objects you want to bind to a list and DataBind the objects to the repeater.

```
var hotelsList = new List<Ron>();
hotelsList.Add(originalRon);
hotelsList.Add(changedRon);
rptrHotels.DataSource = hotelsList;
rptrHotels.DataBind();
```

The properties in the Ron class will be bound like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrHotels" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <div class="label">  
                RONId: 
            </div>  
            <div class="value">
                <%#Eval("RONId")%>
            </div>
        </div>
        ....
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely doable, and no need to do it in compiled code -- you can just bind directly to stuff in your item template:

```
    <div class="label">  
        Hotel: 
    </div>  
    <div class="value">
        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Hotel") %>
    </div>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkMap" runat="server" Command='<%# ((MyClass)Container.DataItem).MyProperty %>'>Map</asp:LinkButton></div>
</div>
```